# I am making a leveling system on a raspberry pi but it says the file doesnt exist

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, discord

The code that use:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    await update_data(users, member)

    with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot == False:
        with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)

        await update_data(users, message.author)
        await add_experience(users, message.author, 5)
        await level_up(users, message.author, message)

        with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)

    await client.process_commands(message)


async def update_data(users, user):
    if not f'{user.id}' in users:
        users[f'{user.id}'] = {}
        users[f'{user.id}']['experience'] = 0
        users[f'{user.id}']['level'] = 1


async def add_experience(users, user, exp):
    users[f'{user.id}']['experience'] += exp


async def level_up(users, user, message):
    with open('levels.json', 'r') as g:
        levels = json.load(g)
    experience = users[f'{user.id}']['experience']
    lvl_start = users[f'{user.id}']['level']
    lvl_end = int(experience ** (1 / 4))
    if lvl_start < lvl_end:
        await message.channel.send(f'{user.mention} has leveled up to level {lvl_end}')
        users[f'{user.id}']['level'] = lvl_end

@client.command()
async def level(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if not member:
        id = ctx.message.author.id
        with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        lvl = users[str(id)]['level']
        await ctx.send(f'You are at level {lvl}!')
    else:
        id = member.id
        with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        lvl = users[str(id)]['level']
        await ctx.send(f'{member} is at level {lvl}!')
```

The error i got:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'users.json'

I am doing it on a raspberry pi and i dont know how to direct the files
Btw the code is for a leveling system that im making
I tried to direct it with the line: os.chdir(r'')
But that didnt work

The path:/home/pi/Desktop/Bot
Bot is a map

Comment: Have you double-checked that the json exists next to your python script. Also, it could because files are resolved relative to CWD (by mistake)

Comment: If you are having troubles with relative file paths, try it with the full absolute file path (starting with `/`).

Comment: Alexander what do you men with next to your python scipt?

Comment: Klaus, it starts with a / but how do i say to the script that the script has to look in my folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you need is:

```
import os

path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Desktop', 'Bot', 'users.json')
path1 = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Desktop', 'Bot', 'levels.json')
```

and to open the file:

```
with open(path, 'r')as g:
```